# In IE 11, th tag's after pseudo element doesn't work properly

Tags: css, html-table, pseudo-element

```css
table {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

tr, th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

th:after {
  background: #000;
  bottom: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1px;
}

td {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

th + td:before {
  background: #000;
  bottom: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line</th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Line<br>Line<br>Line</th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Line</th>
    <td>Line<br>Line<br>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- new problem arise -->
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Line</th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have the right border for `th` tag, with some even gaps in both top and bottom. Like what I said in the title, I use `after` pseudo element for `th` tag and it doesn't work in IE 11. Please see code attached for detail bug.

Could anyone suggest me any solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

**Update**

I implemented @Mr Lister's solution, and it worked well with single row `th` + `td` tag.

Another bug arose is that when I used `th` with `rowspan`, and the behavior in IE 11 is once again, broken. Could you please help me to thoroughly solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug alright. I'm not sure there is a solution, but here is a workaround.

In addition to the line inside the th, draw another line inside the td following it (in the same position on the screen of course).

```css
table {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

tr, th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

th:after {
  background: #000;
  bottom: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1px;
}

/* this is new */
th + td::before {
  background: #000;
  bottom: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1px;
}

td {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative; /* and I added this line */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Line</th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Line<br>Line<br>Line</th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Line</th>
    <td>Line<br>Line<br>Line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `left: -3px` in the new block is meant to put the new line in the same position as the old one.
Note that this depends on the value of the table's `border-spacing` property, which is 2px by default, but which I suspect you meant to be 0. If you change that, adjust this one accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! It worked well.

However, there is another bug arising, in which I use `rowspan`. Please see the updated version above and I hope that you would help me to solve this bug.

Comment: @TylerBean Pfff, like I said, I don't have a real solution; this was only a workaround. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: I found the "better" workaround :D. Using the legendary `position: absolute` with extra tag inside `th` and some help from jquery and it worked perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from jQuery, I achieved what I want perfectly with an extra tag inside `th`.

```js
(function($) {
  var $span = $("th").find("span");
  $span.each(function(index, span) {
    var $th = $(span).closest("th");
    var height = $th.height();
    $(span).css({
      "height": height
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
table {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

tr, th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

th {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

th > span {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

th > span:after {
  background: #000;
  bottom: 30px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1px;
}

td {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span>Line</span></th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><span>Line<br>Line<br>Line</span></th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><span>Line</span></th>
    <td>Line<br>Line<br>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- new problem arise -->
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"><span>Line</span></th>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```